# Most portable decompression file format, and command

Tags: shell, zsh, posix, compression, compatibility

Looking for a file format that is guaranteed to have a decompression command preinstalled on all POSIX Unix/Linux installations. The `.Z` file can be decompressed by `uncompress`. But am not sure if `uncompress` is found on all POSIX-compliant Linux/Unix installations, as both `compress` and `uncompress` are defined in XSI extensions. So far in my testing, macOS, BSD Unix and Linuxes seem to have `uncompress` or `zcat` (which is equivalent to `uncompress -c`). Not sure if there is a Unix flavor or Linux distribution that does not have either `uncompress` or `zcat`.

If there is no single command, am open to the idea of a comprehensive list of decompression commands that will cover all Unixes/Linuxes and have a format that they all support.

NOTE: I am not looking for a software library that is posix and compatible. The solution would be a shell command, or a zsh-only solution if someone has implemented a zsh compression/decompression utility.

Comment: `uncompress ` is compliant with IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (“POSIX.1”) but, as you pointed out, the utility is not always installed under that name. You’ll have to do a runtime check to see if you can use it or drop back to `gzip`.

Comment: @doneal24 Do you think it is a error on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands to list ``uncompress`` and ``zcat`` as type Optional (XSI)? Where did you read that it is compliant? Thanks!

Comment: The wiki table lists compress/uncompress as optional. My link is [here](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.8/compress.1).

Comment: @doneal24 They list it as optional to POSIX, so it is not POSIX complaint. That is the reason it states "compliant with the X/Open System Interfaces option of the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 ", and wiki page does not tag it with option code: "Mandatory" . That is no different from my description "...as both compress and uncompress are defined in XSI extensions". Practically speaking yes I can fallback on gzip, then I would be looking for a comprehensive list of commands that would cover decompressing a .Z file on all Unies/Linuxes.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the same for GNU Parallel.

I tested old versions of:

openstep qnx pidora alpha tru64 hpux-ia64 syllable raspbian solaris openindiana aix hpux debian-ppc suse solaris-x86 mandriva ubuntu scosysv unixware centos miros macosx redhat netbsd openbsd freebsd debian dragonfly vax ultrix minix irix hurd

and the most installed tool was `bzip2`. Unfortunately I cannot remember which ones did not have it.

I am not sure if it is required by POSIX. My test was done in a real world scenario, and maybe that is good enough for you.

Comment: Thanks Ole, yes it is not required by POSIX. But good to learn about your experience. As a side note, where would one ask people who maintain POSIX standard to add some compression/decompression command to their set of mandatory commands? Maybe they can just promote ``compress``, ``uncompress``, and ``zcat`` to "mandatory" in an updated standard. Perhaps they couldn't do it back then, and can now for reasons best known to them (including but not limited to licensing and patents).

Comment: @reportaman What's the use of making `bzip2` or any other particular utility mandatory in POSIX if extremely few Linux distributions are certified? One of the _points_ of not certifying a distribution is to allow it to be stripped down, have all parts replaced, and make it special purpose, with or without decompression facilities.  This is why GNU refused to standardise Emacs (it would mean an unwanted feature freeze) and why it was Vi that became the standard editor.  Is this a case of "there's something wrong with the compiler", but on a distribution basis?

Comment: @Kusalananda There are a lot of assumptions in your argument. I think it is better left for another forum. My question to Ole was where would one send a communication to people who maintain POSIX.

Comment: @reportaman Look for "the Austin Group".